# How to Efficiently Learn Proprietary Information in a Challenging Work Environment?

Tags: work-environment, career-development

I work as a Linux System Administrator in a fintech company in Nepal. My responsibilities involve working with mobile banking architecture, understanding the flow of events in mobile banking, and handling interactions with ISO servers. Additionally, I need to understand how certain database flags are affected under specific scenarios, such as failed renewals due to insufficient balances for charge deductions.

The problem I'm facing is that there is limited documentation available for these tasks, and the existing documentation is not very helpful. Previous ticket resolutions also lack the necessary details for me to learn from. Currently, my only option is to seek guidance from senior colleagues, but this approach is becoming quite burdensome for both me and them.

I am seeking advice on how to effectively cope with these challenges and learn the intricacies of this system. Unlike developers who can rely on extensive online resources, I cannot simply Google my way through this learning process, as a deep understanding of the system is crucial in my role. Since my company operates in the fintech sector, I believe the architecture might be similar to Indian fintech systems like Paytm or American systems like PayPal.

Therefore, I am looking for any suggestions on how to efficiently learn and gain expertise in this proprietary information would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There often is no efficient way. The best way may be to spend time improving the documentation.

Comment: *"Therefore, I am looking for any available documents or resources that explain the architecture of such fintech systems"* - This is off-topic. The answer is "google it"/"we are not a search engine". However, the other question you ask is on-topic so I'll edit your post.

Comment: How long ago did you join this company?

Comment: 4 months it has been

Comment: **Currently, my only option is to seek guidance from senior colleagues** - If the documentation is lacking, then you have no choice but to seek guidance from senior colleagues. You didn't create this problem. If it's becoming burdensome to all involved, then get guidance from your manager on how you should proceed.

Comment: @joeqwerty that's answer material ;)

Answer (score 1):

> Currently, my only option is to seek guidance from senior colleagues.

If the documentation is lacking, then you have no choice but to seek guidance from senior colleagues. You didn't create this problem. If it's becoming burdensome to all involved, then get guidance from your manager on how you should proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Use the test system if there is one. Best way to learn what everything does is to try everything out yourself and observe the workflow. There's nothing particularly difficult about financial software. It's just tracking numbers and compliance.

Answer (score 0):

Your company has chosen to employ you, pay you, and trust you. They want you to succeed in your job. Properly managed companies, when hiring people, understand that training them is a necessary and fruitful investment of money and senior peoples' time. So don't be embarrassed to ask questions and get help from good people. Seriousy.

Make an appointment with your supervisor, let them know the topic is "training", and ask them the question you asked us. Ask for suggestions for training materials and other ways to learn more about your job and your company's operations. Most supervisors welcome  such questions.

If your company uses a cloud provider like AWS / Baidu / Azure, it may help you to get a free-tier account of your own to try out a few things. That might be worth your trouble. Your free account, of course, will stand alone and not have any access to your company's data, so it's only for experimenting.

And, be aware that fintech companies, and other companies handling sensitive user data, don't often publish their internal systems architectures for the general public to read about. Because cybercriminals.